# why sql:variable(@variable) doesn't work?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am doing this:

```
while(@i<=@counting)
begin       
    select @Id = R.DATAROW.value('T_ID[sql:variable("@i")]','int')
    from @selectedXML.nodes('/NewDataSet/child::MainTable[1]') as R(DATAROW)
```

If I put something like:

```
select @Id= R.DATAROW.value('T_ID[1]','int')
```

takes the value correctly for the first table, but I want to insert the `@i` to get it for all my tables.

Someone can help please?

Thank you

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: @rhealitycheck this is XQuery in SQL Server 2005+.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this exactly, but I think you might need to use the full form of specifying the array position:

```
select @Id = R.DATAROW.value('T_ID[position() = sql:variable("@i")]','int')
```